# Bluetooth Mate Gold connected to Arduino Mega not Receiving Data from Tera Term

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm having trouble communicating between Tera Term and an Arduino Mega over a bluetooth connection. My goal is to be able to set up the Mega so it can be later used to exchange text commands with a C++ application. Using the code I've found on this site, I can use the Arduino IDE Serial Monitor to send text to the Tera Term terminal, but I cannot send text from the Tera Term terminal to the Arduino. It never recognizes text was sent from the terminal. The bluetooth module I am using is the Bluetooth Mate Gold from SparkFun. The code's purpose is to detect incoming chars and then activate an LED. My code is shown below:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int bluetoothTx = 15;
int bluetoothRx = 14;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(115200);
  bluetooth.print("$$$");
  delay(100);
  bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available()) {
  char toSend = (char)bluetooth.read();
  Serial.print(toSend);
  flashLED();
  }

  //Read from usb serial to bluetooth
  if(Serial.available()) {
  char toSend = (char)Serial.read();
  bluetooth.print(toSend);
  flashLED();
  }
}

void flashLED() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

The only thing that seems to work from Tera Term is entering command mode using "$$$." Doing that, I can run commands such as "D." I'm not sure why I can't send chars from Tera Term to the Arduino and have them be read. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: An obvious possibility would be faulty wiring or desgination in the sketch of the pin carrying data from the module to the Arduino.  Ordinary soft serial is known to have issues though there are alternate versions.  On a mega though, you have additional hardware serial ports you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I just built the same thing and i had to add a delay of 500 ms before configuring the module. I also had problems with receiving data since i used pin that did not support the PCINT interrupt.

```
delay(500);
bluetooth.begin(115200); 
bluetooth.print("$"); 
bluetooth.print("$");
bluetooth.print("$"); 
delay(100);  
bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");  
bluetooth.begin(9600);
```